# ¿Subir Aplicación Web Con GoLang y React Js A Un Servidor?

Tags: go, deployment

Estoy pensando en realizar una app con un FrontEnd hecho en React Js y con el BackEnd hecho en GoLang, pero la verdad ahorita no tengo ni idea como desplegar la app a producción, he esta investigando pero no he encontrado mucha información al respecto. No se si se necesita alojar el BackEnd en diferente lugar que el FrontEnd, o si va dentro del mismo Hosting. Si alguien me pudiera orientar se lo agradecería mucho.

Answer (score 0):

Tomando de ejemplo que ya tienes tu web app con react y tu backend hecho con Go. 
Hay varias formas de hacerlo, pero la mas clásica es que Go regrese el index.html y tengas una carpeta publica con tus assets. 
En tu servidor tendrías que:

1. Crear un archivo de systemd para ejecutar y detener el servicio de
   Go que previamente compiles.
2. Deberás configurar Apache o Nginx, y configurar los proxies para que
   Go pueda salir. Si podrias hacer que tu compilado salga por el
   puerto 80 pero lo recomendable es que un web server se encargue de esto.
3. Para tener un poco de experiencia , puedes hacer el tutorial de heroku => https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-go , o el ejemplo de Digitalocean => https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-go-web-application-using-nginx-on-ubuntu-18-04

Saludos